# Standardization of density functions

Tags: density-function

I have the density function $$f(x)= \frac {e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}.$$
The integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $1$ so it is indeed a density function. The expected value of the function is $0$ and the variance is $\pi^2/3$.

My goal is to set the variance to $1$ but leaving the expected value at $0$ and of course the Integral of $f(x)$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ should stay at $1$ in order to have a density. But I am clueless of how to do it.
Also is there a general way to perform this kind of task for any given density function?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $g(x)$ is a density function, then so is
$$
a\cdot g(ax)
$$
for any $a\in (0, \infty)$.

Comment: So what you are saying is, that I should add an constant a to the density and I assume a is the inverse of the variance ($a=\frac{3}{pi^2}$)

Comment: @user2968163 I think you should let $a$ be the inverse of the _standard deviation_, not the variance, but I can never keep those straight in my head. You will have to check.

Comment: It's strange but neither is working. I also chose other densities and also neither the inverse of the variance nor the standard deviation is working

Comment: I think I got it now. The term a must be just the standard deviation (not the inverse) which seems kind of odd to me. But at least in my calculations in R it gives me the right results

Comment: Well, that makes sense, the moment I actually stop to think about it. The graph of $g(2x)$ is _narrower_ than the graph of $g(x)$, after all. So if the variance (and standard deviation) is too large, then the graph is too wide, so you want $a$ to be larger than $1$ in order to make it narrower.